# how to read json data in django?

Tags: python, json, django

How do I read data from JSON object sent by an android form (by get method) to a django python server?

I've tried this

```
def post_article(sample):      #sample is the http request   
    json = sample.read()
    data = json.loads(json) 
    a = data['title']
    response_data = {}
    response_data['title'] = a 
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

I am just returning the content of the request as it is to check my working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shadowing the `json` module with a local variable by using the same name, try using a different variable name instead.

```
def post_article(sample):      #sample is the http request   
    json_data = sample.read()
    data = json.loads(json_data) 
    a = data['title']
    response_data = {}
    response_data['title'] = a 
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: @ParitoshWalvekar I meant more specifically- is there a traceback on the error page, or in the django logs?